# how do you run a php file from ssh?

Tags: php, linux, ssh

I'm using from ssh:

```
php filename.php
```

and works great, but when I do this:

```
php filename.php?id=2
```

I get a "could not open input file" error.

any ideas?

Comment: Logical, you have no file named `filename.php?id=2`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475344/call-php-document-with-ssh-includes-get-variable

Answer (score 9):

You can't pass GET variables via the command line!! If you need to pass a variable to your script you can use `php filename.php your_variable` and use `$argv` and `$argc` in your PHP code.

- http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.argc.php
- http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.argv.php

Answer (score 1):

PHP file's that were written as a website will only be of limited use on CLI.

You could write a wrapper script, that prepares the superglobals and `include`'s the webscript.

I recommend reading about the [CLI interface](http://php.net/cli) to understand what it does.

Answer (score 1):

The `filename.php?id=2` syntax is only for web servers.

What you did was tell the shell to find a file named `filename.php?id=2` and pass it to PHP, but that file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your parameters as arguments instead and use $argv:

```
<?php
var_dump($argv);
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php